# Text mesh scaling camera distance relative

Tags: unity, c#

I am searching a fromula that can maintain my text mesh size according to the distance from camera. I want that no matter my camera is near or far from text mesh my text show always with same width an height. I have tried this but the problem is still persist somehow

```
float  size = (activeCam.transform.position - transform.position).magnitude;
            newLocalScale = new Vector3(size / 108, size / 108, size / 108);
            transform.localScale = newLocalScale;
```

[image]

Comment: The only way I can think of doing this easily would be to fake it. That is, rather than scaling the text, position it so that it is at a fixed distance from the camera, or using a second camera. Doing it the way you're doing it would require undoing the math that computes perspective. That said, have you tried using the square of the magnitude? The square root?

Comment: @Draco18s Can you share a possible solution? i can change the position it is in world space, denoting specific point

Comment: I did it once, but I'm not in a position to work out the math again. Involved LookAt() and using vector math to move the transform to a spot that was a given distance from the camera. I've got a script around somewhere, but at home and I'm not at home.

Comment: well OK i am also using LookAt

Comment: Ah, now that I'm sitting down, `camera.pos + (text.forward * -distance)` that's the vector math. Do be aware that if your camera moves, you'll have to recalculate every frame and will have to do so based on the text's *original* location and it is possible for the offset to push the text through walls, etc.

Comment: what is this ? is it text position ?

Comment: That would be the location to move the text *to* so that it is a given distance from the camera *after* using `LookAt()`, e.g. `text.pos = camera.pos + (text.forward * -distance)` (mind the shorthand).

Comment: well i implement it seems impressive but not applicable for me as it is changing the text position which seriously i can't afford. Because sometime my text are collapsing with each other. there are different text and as position become changed it become collapsed. Is there any other solution please where i dont change the position of text

Comment: Wait let me check it again . i did one mistake sorry

Comment: Sorry mate, problem still persist